# Eclipse CDT toolchain question

Tags: eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I want to use Eclipse CDT as an editor. I work in windows machine (since it more poserfull compiuter), while the toolchain resides on the linux box. Now I open Eclipse, create empty project in the proper directory (disk on linux machine where the sources reside) and I add the sources (just drag-n-drop) into the project. All I want is ability to make crossreference and to colorize the syntax. Now I need to add the proper include directories and ... I have only the "cygwin gcc" with preconfigured include pathes, that I cannot remove. I want to define my own enviroment with include pathes, compiler etc.
How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might hack your way using a Standard Make Project. This will make Eclipse CDT use a `Makefile` of yours in which you can define the proper `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, compiler etc.

Not that going the Standard Make Project means that you'll somehow have to keep the source directory and files in sync between Eclipe and the content of your `Makefile`.

Comment: Thanks. Where to take the "Standard Make Project", that i need to modify?

Comment: Hmm I don't have CDT at hand, but you can surely modify your existing project to use a standard make build

Answer (score 0):

I use CDT Internal Builder and MS Visual C++ Toolchain in my project in Eclipse. The problem is that the compiler swears:

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   std::basic_istream> & getline(char *, ?)
>   std::basic_istream> & getline(char *, ?, char)
>   '

when I'm tapping something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream fin;
char buf[256];

fin.open("in.txt", fstream::in);
fin.getline(buf, 256); // !!!!!

return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?